# Cannot access protected property CI_Pagination

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit

Cannot access protected property `CI_Pagination

Trying to add submit button on last page of pagination currently it's on every page by default...on line 49 i have condition to check whether i am in last page or not, I want a submit button at the end of the pagination page

Code on which error is showing..please explain how to implement

```
if($this->pagination->cur_page >= ceil($this->pagination->total_rows / $this->pagination->per_page))
{
    $isLastPage = true; 
}else{
    $isLastPage = false;
}
```

Pagination code

```
public function quizdisplay()
{   
    //echo $this->pagination->create_links();

    //$this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xampp/cii/index.php/Questions/quizdisplay';
    //$config['total_rows'] = 10;
    $total_row = $this->quizmodel->record_count();
    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = $total_row;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
    }else{
        $page = 1;
    }

    $data["results"] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions($config["per_page"], $page);
    $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    View data according to array.
    $this->load->view("play_quiz", $data);
}
```

Both the codes are in same function

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: sure sir, i'll follow, do you have any fixes or any suggestion for this problem

Comment: `$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ` this show current page . Why you want to access protected member ?

Comment: i am fetching 10 data from data base showing all those 10 data one by one using pagination, at last 10th page i want submit button how to implement that

Comment: Just a tip rather than putting your url like  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xampp/cii/index.php/Questions/quizdisplay';` it is just easer to do  `$config['base_url'] = base_url('questions/quizdisplay');` make sure you have set the base url on config.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thank you..I want to sustain/hold data, whatever user has been checked..it's getting unchecked whenever i switch to next for next question